# Cakephp updating session

Tags: php, cakephp

If I create a Session then update it after a few minutes before session expires, does it actually reset the timeout for session whenever update is made?

This is for Cakephp.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you can save and control your sessions from within CakePHP.

Please [take a further look at the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1310/Sessions) to see what you're using.

Nevertheless your logic is, by all means, correct.